# Can't login after forgot password using Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a simple app with login and forgot password using email OTP feature.

I experienced a problem where I cannot login using an account that I recently changed the password using a "Forgot Password" function. I think that the "Forgot Password" function is correct as it correctly changes the password based on my Firebase database. But whenever I use the account that I changed the password, I cannot login to the user even if the credentials are correct. Whenever I use a user account that does not have used the forgot password, the user is successfully logged in.

This is my code. I don't know why the system calls the "else" statement rather than the "if" even if user credentials are correct.
[Login Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0Axh.png)

Hope anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use VerifyCode (opt) function:  FirebaseAuth.Instance.VerifyPasswordResetCode
and make sure email is verified
FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.IsEmailVerified

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).